# Problem in converting Javascript code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and i want to convert following javascript code for dropdown menu to jquery

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active1");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

My code till now is

```
$(".dropdown-btn").each( function() {
   $(this).click(function () {
     var dropdownContent = $(this).parent().next();
     dropdownContent.show();
     alert(dropdownContent.val());
     alert("jquery.....");
  });
});
```

Following is HTML code:

```
<button class="dropdown-btn">1</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="" target="_blank">1</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">2</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">3</a>
</div>

<button class="dropdown-btn">2</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="" target="_blank">3</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">1</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the convertion? I mean there's no question in the post, you just have let us know that you're doing this ...

Comment: @freefaller that would be more of a CodeReview thing, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please, add your question and your connected html (example) code to your question.

Comment: `$(".dropdown-btn").click(function () {
 $(this).next().toggle();
});`

Comment: Why have you used `$(this).parent().next()` when your original is `$(this).next()` ?

Comment: JQuery IS Javascript.

Comment: @ChrisG  Your ans is right give your suggestion as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @nagi I would, but this question is unlikely to help anybody else. Even if somebody makes the same mistake of inserting `.parent()` where they shouldn't; the chances of them finding this question are essentially zero.

Comment: Voting close as simple typo

Comment: @Dementic yes, but javascript is *not* jquery...  if it makes it easier, just read these questions as "convert vanilla javascript to jquery javascript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look and tell me if works.

```
$(".dropdown-btn").click(function () {
  $(this).toggle("active1");
  var dropdownContent = $(this).next();
  $(dropdownContent).toggle();
});
```